# How to get (only) author name or email in git given SHA1?

Tags: git, commit, sha1, author

I would like to check for author's e-mail and name, surname to verify who's pushing to my repo.

Is there any way that I can come up with a command in git to show commiter's name/e-mail given only SHA1 of the commit?

This is what I came up with but it's far from ideal solution (the first solution is for git hook that's why it's using 2 SHA1s with `rev-list`. The second one simply uses `git show`):

```
git rev-list -n 1 --pretty=short  ccd3970..6ddf170 | grep Author | cut -d ' ' -f2- | rev | cut -d ' ' -f2- | rev
git show 6ddf170 | grep Author | cut -d ' ' -f2- | rev | cut -d ' ' -f2- | rev
```

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You can use the following command:

```
 git log --format='%ae' HASH^!
```

It works with `git show` as well. You need to include `-s` to suppress the diff.

```
git show -s --format='%ae' HASH
```

Comment: It does work with `git show`, but `git show` first shows the commit info as specified by `format`, and then the diff. To suppress the diff, add the `-s` option (aka `--no-patch`).

Comment: You are right. So the best way would be a simple: `git show -s --format='%ae' HASH`

Comment: Or the equally simple `git log -1 --format='%ae' HASH` for yet another alternative :)

Answer (score 28):

```
git show <commit_id> | grep Author
```

Using git show + pipe + grep works!

Answer (score 14):

This will show - sha, committer email, author email

```
git log --pretty=format:"%h %ce %ae" HASH
```

Comment: For this you need to add HASH at the end, otherwise it produces output for all commits instead of for single commit

Answer (score 4):

If you want the author's name instead of e-mail, the following works:

```
git show -s --format='%an' HASH
```

The difference from the other answers is the format string (`%an` vs `%ae`).