# Show e-mail address for user in GitKraken

Tags: git, gitkraken

I'm using GitKraken to view a repository. I've clicked a specific commit and on the righthand side it shows the commit details. In that panel it shows the commit user too:

[image: commit author in GitKraken's commit details panel]

But it doesn't show the e-mail address for the user anywhere. How can I get it to show the e-mail address, or at least find out what it is, from within GitKraken?

I've tried:

- hovering, hoping for a tooltip
- right-clicking the commit author
- double-clicking the commit author
- checking [the GitKraken FAQ](https://support.gitkraken.com/faq)
- using [the GitKraken Search](https://support.gitkraken.com/?search=email)

all to no avail.

Is it possible to show the commit author e-mail address in GitKraken?

Comment: Not possible I think. I also tried to view profile of other user without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitKraken doesn't show email of commit.
Try to use https://stackoverflow.com/a/29876744/7427923 for getting info about commit's email.

Comment: I suppose this answer, which comes down to "not possible", is the only acceptable answer at the moment.