# Jenkins Pipeline Script: Send Email notification through

Tags: linux, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops

I want to send email notifications through a Jeenkins Scripted Pipeline, when any job gets done. Email to a specific developer/group who checked into git. I need help with said script.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Email-ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin), configure it with docs and add similar code:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh "sh deploy.sh"
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            emailext body: 'Hello sainath kadaverugu', recipientProviders: [$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider'], subject: 'After build message'
        }
    }
}
```

If You want to get last committer email address checkout this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29876342/how-to-get-only-author-name-or-email-in-git-given-sha1)

**EDIT**: in "node-style" I used [mailer](https://plugins.jenkins.io/mailer)

```
def get_mail() {
    node('master'){
        USER_MAIL = wrap([$class: 'BuildUser']) {
            return env.BUILD_USER_EMAIL
        }
    }
}

def USER_MAIL = get_mail()

node('master') {
   stage('Checkout') {
       deleteDir()
       git 'git@sometest.git'
    }

    stage('Deploy') {
        sh "sh depoly.sh"
    }
    step([$class: 'Mailer', notifyEveryUnstableBuild: true, recipients: USER_MAIL, sendToIndividuals: true])
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, we have requirement of pipeline node script, please help me with node script(same script in node).with success or failure status